# How to select a specific customer?

Tags: mysql, sql

I create the following tables:

```
create table customers (
        ID      varchar(9),
        name    varchar(15), 
        CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

create table living_places (
        code    varchar(7),
        ID      varchar(9),
        CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);

create table policies (
        code_policy         varchar(7),
        code_living_place   varchar(7),
        CONSTRAINT pk_code_policy PRIMARY KEY (code_policy)
);

create table bills (
        code          varchar(7),
        code_policy   varchar(7),
        paid_out      boolean,
        CONSTRAINT pk_code_bill PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

I inserted the following dates:

```
insert into customers(ID, name) values('fx1','Louis');
insert into customers(ID, name) values('fx2','Peter');
insert into customers(ID, name) values('fx3','Alice');

insert into living_places(code, ID) values('001','fx1');
insert into living_places(code, ID) values('002','fx2');
insert into living_places(code, ID) values('003','fx1');
insert into living_places(code, ID) values('004','fx3');

insert into policies(code_policy, code_living_place) values('p1','001');
insert into policies(code_policy, code_living_place) values('p2','002');
insert into policies(code_policy, code_living_place) values('p3','003');

insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) values('b1','p1','1');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) values('b2','p1','1');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) values('b3','p2','0');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) values('b4','p2','1');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) values('b5','p3','0');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) values('b6','p3','1');
```

The question is: **How to select those people which have all their policies paid?**

My problem is that `Louis` has two policies `p1` and `p3`. Policy `p1` is paid but `p3` is not.

My query:

```
select ID from living_places where code in (
select code from living_places where code in (
select code_living_place from policies where code_policy in (
select code_policy from bills where paid_out=1 and code_policy not in (
select code_policy from bills where paid_out=0))));
```

MySQL return me:

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
| fx1  |
+------+
```

P.S: `Louis` dont have all the policies paid. For example, the bill `b5` is not paid.

Comment: There's literally 0 people in your example that will have all their policies paid.  Since you're not even including the 3rd person in your example (There is no policy 004, hence no reference to person fx3) and everyone else has at least one bill not paid.

Answer (score 2):

I think should be this:

```
select name 
from customers
where id not in ( 
    select iving_places.id 
    from living_places
    inner join policies on policies.code_living_place = living_places.code
    inner join bills on ( bills.code_policy = policies.code and bills.paid_out=0)
);
```

Comment: But i need the people who have ALL the polices paid. , ie, no person in this case. Thank for the answer

Comment: No @scaisEdge, because the policie "P3"  is from "Louis" and the bill "b5" have paid_out="0". And fx1="Louis"

Comment: It would work if Alice actually had a policy in this example.  Because she doesn't she also doesn't have a moment where she'll have a paid_out=0;  Since that doesn't occur her ID will be used in the name/ID select you have.  The only change you'd probably have to make is to make sure a person has some policy in the database.  If not, then exclude them.

Comment: I have update the answer with only whi have policeis

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it's this:

```
select c.ID, c.name
from customers c
where c.ID in (
    select lp.id
    from policies p
    join living_places lp on p.code_living_place = lp.code
    join bills b on b.code_policy = p.code_policy
    group by lp.id
    having sum(b.paid_out = 1) = count(*));
```

It returns 0 records with the data you currently have and if you modify the one bill Louis hasn't paid to paid then he will show up in the results.

[Here's a SQL Fiddle to play around with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b641f/49)

Comment: Really nice idea to use having sum(b.paid_out = 1) = count(*)

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
select c.ID from customers c
  join living_places l
    on l.ID = c.ID
  join policies p
    on p.code_living_place = l.code
  join bills b
    on b.code_policy = p.code_policy
where paid_out = 0
group by c.ID
```

Comment: You might want to add a `DISTINCT` or otherwise handle cases where a customer owes on more than one policy.

Answer (score 1):

```
I take it you want customer who have policies paid out i.e paid_out=1?
If yes, this following should do:

select c.ID, c.name
from customers c, living_places l, policies p
where c.ID = l.ID
and l.code = p.code_living_place
and p.code_policy not in (select distinct b.code_policy 
                          from bills b
                          where b.paid_out = '0')
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b641f/6) where you can see the results.

EDIT: This query will work when the customer has one or zero policy (i.e. one or zero houses). **The query needs attention for > 1 house/policy.**

Comment: But MYSQL return "Louis" and "Peter" and they dont have all the bills paid.

Comment: @Python241820, ah ok I missed that last part. Let me tweak my solution.

Comment: "Louis" has two houses with 2 policies and one of them is not paid at all

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the repeated post , the answer was :

```
SELECT x.name
FROM
(SELECT c.name, SUM(CASE WHEN b.paid_out THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) all_paid
FROM customers c JOIN living_places l ON c.ID = l.ID
JOIN policies p ON l.code = p.code_living_place
JOIN bills b ON p.code_policy = b.code_policy
GROUP BY c.name) x
WHERE x.all_paid = 0;
```

response by @David Bachmann Jeppesen: [Select a specific customer in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082421/select-a-specific-customer-in-mysql/37082654#37082654)