# Select a specific customer in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I create the following tables:

```
create table customers

(
        ID             varchar(9),
        name           varchar(15),  

CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


create table living_places
(
        code     varchar(7),
        ID      varchar(9),

CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);

create table policies
(
        code_policy         varchar(7),
        code_living_place       varchar(7),

CONSTRAINT pk_code_policy PRIMARY KEY (code_policy)
);

create table bills
(
        code          varchar(7),
        code_policy   varchar(7),
        paid_out      boolean,

CONSTRAINT pk_code_bill PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
I inserted the following dates:
```

I inserted the following dates:

```
insert into customers(ID, name) 
values('fx1','Louis');
insert into customers(ID, name) 
values('fx2','Peter');
insert into customers(ID, name) 
values('fx3','Alice');

insert into living_places(code, ID) 
values('001','fx1');
insert into living_places(code, ID) 
values('002','fx2');
insert into living_places(code, ID) 
values('003','fx1');
insert into living_places(code, ID) 
values('004','fx3');

insert into policies(code_policy, code_living_place) 
values('p1','001');
insert into policies(code_policy, code_living_place) 
values('p2','002');
insert into policies(code_policy, code_living_place) 
values('p3','003');

insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) 
values('b1','p1','1');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) 
values('b2','p1','1');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) 
values('b3','p2','0');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) 
values('b4','p2','1');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) 
values('b5','p3','0');
insert into bills(code, code_policy, paid_out) 
values('b6','p3','1');
```

The question is: how to select those people which have all their policies paid.

My problem is that "Louis" has two policies "p1" and "p3", "p1" are paid but "p3" are not paid.

My Query:

```
select ID from living_places where code in (
select code from living_places where code in (
select code_living_place from policies where code_policy in (
select code_policy from bills where paid_out=1 and code_policy not in (
select code_policy from bills where paid_out=0))));
```

MySQL return me:

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
| fx1  |
+------+
```

P.S: "Louis" dont have all the policies paid. For example, the bill "b5" are not paid.

Comment: Don't repost the same question twice please.  You already asked this question today and it has answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080951/how-to-select-a-specific-customer.  You need to continue with the same question post you already made and not generate the same thing just to get to the top of the new posts again.  This isn't reddit.

Comment: @Dresden sorry for the repeated post posting, I thought that the problem would read by other people. I will not do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the SUM-CASE approach:

```
SELECT x.name
FROM
(SELECT c.name, SUM(CASE WHEN b.paid_out THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) all_paid
FROM customers c JOIN living_places l ON c.ID = l.ID
JOIN policies p ON l.code = p.code_living_place
JOIN bills b ON p.code_policy = b.code_policy
GROUP BY c.name) x
WHERE x.all_paid = 0;
```

Maybe you could avoid the nested SELECT by using the HAVING clause here also...

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select p.id
from policies p join
     living_places lp
     on p.code = lp.code_living_place join
     bills b
     on b.code_policy = p.code_policy
group by p.id
having sum(b.paid_out = 1) = count(*);
```